# Background applied to the controller not getting applied to table view cells in storyboard swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, storyboard

I have a storyboard consisting of a background image on top of which rests a table. My issue is that the background image gets applied to the table but not to the cells of the table, they still remain white.

What is it that I am doing wrong?
Please help

Comment: provide a code.

Comment: Please update your question with some code so that we can understand what you are upto!

Comment: you should set background color of your tableviewcell to `clearColor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method, use

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set background color as clear color of tableview cell as well as it's content view.

Answer (score 1):

You should do clear back ground color of your cell by below delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but it fills the cell in parts. Like half of the cell gets the background colour, the other half remains white.

Comment: Generally it should be worked but I don't know what you did in cellForRowIndexPath method BTW you got the solution. Cheeerrrr :)